# OpenGL ES; rendering texture created from CGBitmapContext

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures, cgcontext

I am executing the following, which I have derived from a few different tutorials (Just a single render pass, initialisation code not shown but works fine for untextured primitives):

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrthof(0, xSize, 0, ySize, -1.0f, 1.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_SRC_COLOR);

GLuint texture[1];
glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

int width = 50;
int height = 50;
void* textureData = malloc(width * height * 4);
CGColorSpaceRef cSp = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef ct = CGBitmapContextCreate(textureData, width, height, 8, width*4, cSp, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ct, 0, 1, 0, 1);
CGContextFillRect(ct, CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50));
CGContextRelease(ct);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

float verts[] = {
0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
50.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, 50.0f, 0.0f,
50.0f, 50.0f, 0.0f
};

float texCords[] = {
0.0f, 0.0f,
1.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f
};

 glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, verts);
 glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCords);
 glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

 glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

The result is a white square. Not the green one as intended. Can anyone spot the error(s) in my code which result in its' failure to render?

I hope to get this working then move it on to text rendering.

Comment: Should probably say, I know the above even if it did work is horribly inefficient, and that some of it shouldn't even be in the render loop. It's just for the sake of simplicity and getting it working.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `width` and `height` are not powers of two.  There are two solutions:

- Use the texture rectangle extension.  Set the texture target to `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB` instead of `GL_TEXTURE_2D`.  You will have to enable this extension before using it.  Note that rectangle textures do not support mipmaps.
- Use powers of two for texture dimensions.

Comment: `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB` does not appear to be included with iOS 6.0.

Comment: @Justin: This question is two years old.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069441/non-power-of-two-textures-in-ios