# Adding texture to rendered objects results in the object being all black, OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to add a texture to a square using openGL ES 2.0 in Xcode, and I created the square by creating two triangles. When I run the the project the square turns all black. I believe it has something to do with me adding the wrong co-ordinates for the texture.

The structure that holds all the data

```
typedef struct {
float Position[3];
float Color[4];
float TexCoord[2];
} Vertex;
```

The co-ordinates of the position, color, and texture

```
const Vertex Vertices[] = {

//postion    color         Texture
{{1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}},
{{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1}},
{{-1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1}},
{{-1, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}}
};
```

The co-ordinates of the two triangles created

```
const GLubyte Indices[] = {
0, 1, 2,
2, 3, 0
};
```

Seting up texture

```
   - (GLuint)setupTexture:(NSString *)fileName {
   // 1
   CGImageRef spriteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName].CGImage;
   if (!spriteImage) {
       NSLog(@"Failed to load image %@", fileName);
       exit(1);
   }

   // 2
   size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(spriteImage);
   size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(spriteImage);

   GLubyte * spriteData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width*height*4,  sizeof(GLubyte));

   CGContextRef spriteContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(spriteData, width, height, 8, width*4,
                                   CGImageGetColorSpace(spriteImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

   // 3
   CGContextDrawImage(spriteContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), spriteImage);

   CGContextRelease(spriteContext);

   // 4
   GLuint texName;
   glGenTextures(1, &texName);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName);

   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, spriteData);

   free(spriteData);        
   return texName;    
}
```

Instead of using: `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);`

I used: `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_NEAREST);`

But still no luck.

Comment: Show your texture loading code along with your texture. It's probably a power of two issue, [as shown in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069441/non-power-of-two-textures-in-ios).

Comment: Ok adding texture loading code

Comment: I can't find anything regarding texture size. I am following a tutorial. Here is he link, https://www.raywenderlich.com/4404/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial-part-2-textures

Comment: It is a 520 X 346 png file. How can I check whether it is power of two or not

Comment: So it's not a power of two (the width and height aren't `2^N`, e.g `2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128...`). Therefore you want to add the parameters shown in the question I linked to in my original comment. That'll fix the problem.

Comment: I replaced the paramters but still no luck, Ill show in my question

Comment: You need to use all 4 parameters shown.

Comment: Thank you originaluser it worked. Can you post as answer so I can accept

Comment: It's not my answer! As it was a non-power of two issue, this question is now effectively a duplicate. Posting a duplicate answer wouldn't be helpful for the community.

Comment: Unrelated tip, the question being answered: check out `GLKTextureLoader` to avoid having to implement `-setupTexture:` yourself.